# How to translate 'typedef enum' from C to Python?

Tags: python, enums

By necessity, I'm translating a code to Python. But I encountered a structure which I do not know how to build in Python. Follows an example of the code:

```
typedef enum
{
    HCI_CMD = 1,
    ACI_CMD = 2
} hci_cmd_et;
```

Comment: look here https://docs.python.org/3/library/enum.html

Comment: So the goal is to translate this to Python or are you planning to wrap an existing C library in python? You can translate this to python using the enum package (standard library). If you are creating a python wrapper, you can define the enum values as constants.

Comment: @jrast Yes! The general goal is translate an archive from C to Python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see for enums in python

```
from enum import Enum
class hci_cmd_et(Enum):
    HCI_CMD = 1
    ACI_CMD = 2
```